# Tag strong instead h2 at page?

Tags: html, seo

I have list of services in main page with a short description:

```
<div class="services">
<div class="item"><h2>Service 1</h2>Description</div>
<div class="item"><h2>Service 2</h2>Description</div>
<div class="item"><h2>Service 3</h2>Description</div>
<div class="item"><h2>Service 4</h2>Description</div>
</div>
```

What is the best way for SEO? I need to use `h2` or `strong` tag for names of services?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use H2 if you want the crawler to index words in the node as key words for your site. Best to use as few H2s as possible and only one H1 on a single webpage.

Best use scenario example:

```
<div class="services">
<h2>Services Description</h2>
<div class="item"><h3>Service 1</h3><p>Description</p></div>
<div class="item"><h3>Service 2</h3><p>Description</p></div>
<div class="item"><h3>Service 3</h3><p>Description</p></div>
<div class="item"><h3>Service 4</h3><p>Description</p></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: You can see this in practice by putting one of your websites into Nibbler: http://nibbler.silktide.com/ - just be aware that you can only test three websites using the free version so don't waste your efforts putting in sites you didn't create :)